# Jersey: JSON and StringMessageProvider clash, application/json methods generate invalid JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a jax-rs web services on jetty+jersey and tried different JSON message providers (e.g. Jackson and Gson).
With all of them POJO <-> JSON works just fine but methods like this:

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String test() {
    return "This string should be \"quoted\" by message writer";
}
```

produce string

```
This string should be "quoted" by message writer
```

which is of course not a valid JSON and causes browser's ajax calls to fail. 
I expect it to be

```
"This string should be \"quoted\" by message writer"
```

The reason for such magic is StringMessageProvider (one of the internal jersey providers for basic types) which have */* Produce/Consume annotation. And I don't want to hack into jersey internal providers. I want to force jersey to use JSON provider in first place?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after reading jersey docs & some debuging it turned out that:

- yes, custom message readers/writers have higher priority, but
- after selecting "suitable" providers (starting from correct one), jersey sort them via custom comparation, that first checks 'type' distance

So, having method return type 'String' and JSON message provider MIME type wildcard (*/*), it checks first StringMessageProvider (default jersey provider for build-in type) by comparing distances String-String < String-Object.

The problem solved by adding non-generic custom message provider, e.g.:

```
public class StringProvider extends GsonProvider<String> {
    public StringProvider() {}
}
```

(where `GsonProvider implements MessageBodyReader<T>, MessageBodyWriter<T>`).

After this returned string was escaped to be a correct JSON and recognized by browsers' ajax call handlers.

Comment: This is great. No need to use Gson. I did the same by adding a StringMessageBodyWriter that implements MessageBodyWriter<String> and that uses Jackson for the writeTo implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON that you are generating is invalid (you may want to validate it with [*JSONLint*](http://jsonlint.com/)).

So, a valid JSON can be:

```
{"msg":"This string should be \"quoted\" by message writer"}

["This string should be \"quoted\" by message writer"]
```

The Java code for each JSON:

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String, String> test() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("msg", "This string should be \"quoted\" by message writer");
    return map;
}

@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String, String> test() {
    return Arrays.asList("This string should be \"quoted\" by message writer");
}
```

<sub>**NOTE**: I'm using RESTEasy 3.0.8 with Jackson 2.4.1</sub>

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong.
1) http://json.org says: ..."In JSON, they take on these forms: ... a) An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. ... b) An array is an ordered collection of values. ... c) A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number,...". Also you may check out latest JSON RFC http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 where it is said that "string" value is a valid JSON.

Comment: @tuxSlayer - You're returning a *raw string* which is invalid as a *top level* object in JSON. Paul Vargas is returning a **JSON Object** (Map of string -> Object). RFC 7159 says that strings are valid JSON, but only in certain locations. A single raw string is invalid JSON.

Comment: Lets just read it together :) http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-4

A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names. A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array.  Implementations that generate only objects or arrays where a JSON text is called for will be interoperable in the sense that all implementations will accept these as conforming JSON texts.
`JSON-text = ws value ws`,... then follows 'value' definition )

Comment: Ok, you're talking about 7159 which is a *proposed standard* - as explained in the RFC itself: Obsoletes: 4627, 7158                                         March 2014. It's only been around for a handful of months, and it's unlikely that the libraries that you're talking about support that standard. The *previous* standard of 4627 doesn't allow raw strings as top level, as *specifially* mentioned in your comment: **Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array.**

Comment: Ok, agree. But solution was more concise and simple than I though at first, and much more elegant than returning `Map<S, S>`

Comment: @tuxSlayer OK. Can you share your solution? :)